# Warning NullPointerException in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, warnings

When i do:

```
SharedPreferences logData = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

if(logData.getString("myString", null).equals("some_value")) {

    // do some stuff…

} else {

    // do some other…
}
```

Android Studio warnings me that:

> *Method invocation 'logData.getString("myString", null).equals("some_value")' may produce '
>   java.lang.NullPointerException'*

How can I avoid this warning? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getString()` will throw `NUllPointerExcception` because you are returning default **null** value by passing second parameters.

There are two ways to avoid this,

First, by passing empty string as default value as second argument in `getString()`

```
SharedPreferences logData = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

if(logData.getString("myString", "").equals("some_value"))
```

or Second,

First get your String in reference variable than check it for null or not like,

```
String logDataString = logData.getString("myString", null);
if(logDataString  != null && logDataString.equals("some_value"))
```

Comment: The first, so simple.

Comment: There is a two dots typo: logDataString..equals("some_value"))

Comment: Or if `"some_value"` is known to not be null: `"some_value".equals(logData.getString("myString", null))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call equals method on a null object. Try to get the String first and check if it is null.

```
String myString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
    getBaseContext()).getString("myString", null);

if (myString != null) {
    if (myString.equals("something")) {

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Or changing the default value returned by getString method

```
if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
    getBaseContext()).getString("myString", "").equals("")) {

}
```

Comment: Also handle the case where it *is* null properly. If it's expected that it might be sometimes, do whatever works best. If not, then throw an exception (or better consider alternatives where you avoid the situation entirely). In any case, *never fail silently*.

Comment: @tne I agree with you here "never fail silently", for that you can add an "else" in the first example or use the second one. user370305 doesn't handle null exception in his second example too.

Comment: @tne - The `getString()` method provides a functionality where we can accept what we need as by default, in this case we already know if there is nothing than we can return either null or any other string, so we can handle this situation in else part. And in this case Exception handling its not necessary. But on good programming practice I always suggest it.